# Determine if a tree is a DFS Tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

Question goes as:

> We know that there may be many possible DFS trees for a graph depending upon the start vertex and
>   the order in which we explore the neighbors of each vertex.
>   Given a connected graph G = (V, E), you are given a rooted tree T such that each edge of this tree is
>   present in E. Design an efficient algorithm to determine if T is a DFS tree of G.

What is the meaning of "tree T is not a DFS Tree" (assuming it spans the entire graph)?

If I don't have any ordering of tree vertices in the adjacency list representation (which I presume the question inherently claims), I could traverse in any fashion and create the tree that is given in the question.

EDIT : I think I came to know about a "non - DFS tree T", it is simply the tree that spans but isn't possibly creatable in any possible DFS, since we have a restriction that ALL children must be visited first in a DFS tree before returning to parent. Still, can anyone help with the efficient Algo.

eg:

A -- B
      /  \
        C - D

this graph has a Tree T as:
A -- B
      /  \
        C   D

but this isnt a valid DFS tree !
DFS starting at vertex A.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: T is a depth first search tree (DFS) that is what it means

Comment: Can you tell me the relevance of this question `What is the meaning of "tree T is not a DFS Tree" ` as in the question it is said  `T is a DFS tree of G`

Comment: If I can figure out which Tree is not I can figure which tree is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that DFS does not determine uniquely the resulting labeling is due to the fact that there is no order in which the children of a node are visited. To my understanding, checking whether a tree `T` of a given graph `G` is a DFS tree can be done as follows.

Find a node wich has the minimum label in `T`; this will be current node `v` which at this point is the root at which a DFS search is started. Mark `v` as visited.

Recursively process the unvisited children of `v` in `G`. If these are not the same as in `T`, `T` is not a DFS tree of `G`. If they are the same, process them in ascending order of their DFS numbers in `T`, assigning DFS numbers as usual and marking visitied nodes. Whenever the assigned DFS number does not match the DFS number in `T`, the tree `T` cannot be a DFS tree of `G`. If, on the other hand, all DFS numbers can be assigned to match those in `T`, we have constructively proven that `T` is a DFS tree of `G`.

Comment: This will fail in one particular case: 

A : B;
B : C,D;
C : D;
D: C;

If i start at A, and check tree DFS numbers are : A(1), B(2), C(3), D(4). We cant differentiate between the given T and DFS Tree.

Since :


A : B;
B : C,D;
C :B;
D: B;

is not a DFS tree i guess.

Comment: ^ has same DFS numbers of T and DFS tree, but I guess T isnt DFS tree.

Comment: @Akash Please describe the graph and the tree more precisely; in your notation `A : B`, do you mean that `A` has the child `B` ? The graph you mention at the end of your comment is not a tree as it contains a cycle.

Comment: Please see the edited part of above question, I have mentioned it clearly.

Comment: @Akash Thanks for the clarification; I was overlooking that.

Comment: @Akash Please see my updated answer. You are right - in each step, the unvisited children in `G` must be the same as in `T`, otherwise `T` cannot be generated by DFS, ordering by the DFS numbers alone isn't sufficient. Perhaps I have misread the question - in `T`, are the candidate DFS numbers given or is just the tree itself given?

Comment: Ya this works, the important point is that we DFS in original graph according to the DFS numbers in Tree T that we need to check for, and that being done in ascending order of DFS numbers. Cheers !